# Unable to locate package ros-lunar-rosbridge-*

Tags: ros-lunar, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I am trying to install **rosbridge** on Ubuntu 16.04 by running `sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-rosbridge-*`. However I am getting the below errror.

```
 Reading package lists... Done 
 Building dependency tree     
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package ros-lunar-rosbridge-*
 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-lunar-rosbridge-*'
 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ros-lunar-rosbridge-*'
```

Is the rosbridge not released for Lunar version ?

Also kindly let me know if rosbridge installation can be done using github link (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite). If possible kindy let me know the procedure.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307620/unable-to-locate-package-ros-lunar-rosbridge-*/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2018-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbridge_suite` has been released into Lunar, see [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_lunar_default.html?q=rosbridge).

However, that is for `amd64` (ie: x86). You don't tell us what architecture you are using, so I cannot be more specific in my answer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-11-08**:
@gvdhoorn sorry for not providing the details. I am using `intel64`. On an ideal case I believe `sudo apt-get install ros-lunar-rosbridge-*` should work. Right ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-09**:
pedantic, but: `intel64` is not an architecture. Intel's 64bit processors are also called `amd64`.

In any case: if you've setup your `apt` sources correctly, you should be able to install those packages using `apt`, yes.

Please edit your question with more information about your OS, platform, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-09**:
.. how you installed ROS, what the contents is of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`, what the output is of `sudo apt-get update`, etc.

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2018-11-09**:
@gvdhoorn I was able to install `rosbridge` by going back to basics. After setting up the sources.list and keys I was able to install `rosbridge`. Thank you so much for enlightening me on this error from my end.